# link with libc-dbg and libc-prof

Tags: c++, c, linker, libc

I got multiple versions of libc installed,
how do I choose which to link with at compile time?

Right now i'm compiling like

```
g++ prog.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program will link with `libc`. When you run in gdb, libc-dbg will be used to read symbol names, be able to generate backtraces with more informantion, etc. And if you add the `-pg` option when linking, libc-prof will be used and you will be able to use **[gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html)** with your program.

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to path of your libc using following command.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path-to-libc>
```

To check whether program is linked to expected library use

```
ldd a.out
```

This will show you the list of libraries which the program is linked to. :)